# Unable to install profiles to Apple TV 4th gen

Tags: appletv, apple-configurator

I'm trying to add a configuration profile to my Apple TV via Apple Configurator 2, [as documented](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202577), however when I add the profile I get this error:

> **An unexpected error has occurred with “Apple TV”.**
>
> You cannot install apps or other media on Apple TV.
>   [ConfigurationUtilityKit.error – 0x3E9 (1001)]

[image]

In fact, whenever I try to do any management of the Apple TV through Apple Configurator, it fails with the same message.

I've tried:

- I've tried clearing the configuration files (at `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.configurator.*`)
- Updating and reinstalling Apple Configurator
- Restarting computer
- Full factory restore of Apple TV
- Fresh OS X install (on external hard drive)

I'm able to sideload apps through Xcode through the same Mac, so that implies that the USB cable is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found something with similar issues on this thread:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21638

> Process > Perform all Mac updates > reboot   then open the apple
>   configurator again > select store at the top > sign in with apple id.

While it applies to deploying Apps to iPads, the Apple TV runs iOS so the solution may be the same.